# Can we have non-generic help shorthand links?

Tags: feature-request

The existing shorthand links are very useful when answering or to be exact mostly commenting to help mainly new users to improve their questions or show them the way to get into how WPSE works.
But I find it non-practical that all the help shorthand links are showing »help center« as link text. This somewhat leads to the necessity to explain what part of the help is referred to, at least more as it have be, which in my mind foils the use of a shorthand link.
So I'm thinking, wouldn't it be better to have specific links to the help center? And, can we have those shorthand links represent the section they are referring to?

Comment: Fully agree. Often it's really hard to get a well formed English sentence when you _have_ to use "help center" in it. Wasn't forced to "form a sentence, but use that word in it"-games since ground school.

Comment: Yes, it's a little bit annoying and I often tend to do a normal link by hand, just to have a nicer sentence. Maybe it's easier for native speakers - which I'm not. Not to claim that this would make all my sentences perfect, but I'm trying to write good english. Not to mention cases one wants to link two sections, which now is nearly impossible to do nicely.

Comment: I [made my own links](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clippings/) but I agree. The system links need to be better.